# startActivity(new Intent()) in fragments

Tags: android-fragments, android-intent

I have created a fragment and a button on it. When this button is clicked I want the user to be signed out and directed to the `login_page`.
I have defined `signOut()` like this in the ProfileFragment.java file.

```
    void signOut(){
        gsc.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                getActivity().finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(fragment_profile.this,login_page.class));
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Signed out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

fragment_profile is the corresponding xml file of the ProfileFragment.java file.

error is:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'fragment_profile'

This method worked when I used in AppCompatActivity.

Can someone help me with correcting this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Studied more on this and got this as an answer.
`.this` does not work for fragments. Instead, `getContext()` works.

```
getActivity().finish();
startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), login_page.class));
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Signed out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```